# Do different versions of Ruby build Rails projects differently and are there compatibility issues?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I were to run `rails new myapp` using Ruby 1.9.2 and fork this application onto another machine running Ruby 1.9.3, would I be able to run this application? will I have compatibility issues?

Comment: Best answer here: read corresponding Release Notes.

Comment: This is why there are tests. A Ruby point release *usually* won't cause any issues, but check the release notes.

Comment: Are you talking about code that is generated by Rails when you call a generator? I can't answer your question, but hopefully making your question more specific can help.